# Не получается сохранить изображение в Базу данных

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Вот так выглядит класс объекта, который содержит картинку:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Введите название книги")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100, message = "Название книги должно быть от 2 до 100 символов")
    private String title;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Введите имя автора")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100, message = "Имя автора должно быть от 2 до 100 символов")
    private String author;

    @Min(value = 1400, message = "Год издания должен быть больше, чем 1400")
    private int year;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person person;

    @Column(name = "time_assign")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timeAssign;

    @Transient
    private boolean overdue;

    @Column(name = "image_data")
    private byte[] imageData;

    public byte[] getImageData() {
        return imageData;
    }

    public void setImageData(byte[] imageData) {
        this.imageData = imageData;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String title, String author, int year, byte[] imageData) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.year = year;
        this.imageData = imageData;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Date getTimeAssign() {
        return timeAssign;
    }

    public void setTimeAssign(Date timeAssign) {
        this.timeAssign = timeAssign;
    }

    public boolean isOverdue() {
        return overdue;
    }

    public void setOverdue(boolean overdue) {
        this.overdue = overdue;
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит метод save в сервисе:

```
public void save(Book book, MultipartFile imageFile) {
        try {
            if (imageFile != null && !imageFile.isEmpty()) {
                book.setImageData(imageFile.getBytes());
            }
            bookRepository.save(book);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

вот контроллер, отвечающий за добавление новой книги:

```
@PostMapping("/new")
    public String createBook(@ModelAttribute("book") @Valid Book book, @RequestParam("imageData") MultipartFile imageData, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return "books/new";
        bookService.save(book, imageData);
        return "redirect:/books";
    }
```

вот так же HTML форма, в которой пользователь создаёт книгу, тут используется thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Страница добавления книги</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style.css}">
</head>
<body>
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/books/new}" th:object="${book}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="title">Введите название: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" id="title">
    <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}"></div>
    <br/>
    <label for="author">Введите автора: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{author}" id="author">
    <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('author')}" th:errors="*{author}"></div>
    <br/>
    <label for="year">Введите год выпуска: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{year}" id="year">
    <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('year')}" th:errors="*{year}"></div>
    <br/>
    <label for="image">Выберите изображение: </label>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="imageData" accept="image/*">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Создать!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Что я сделал не так? Почему не сохраняется объект в базу данных?
Для полноты картины вот ссылка на репозиторий в гитхаб:
https://github.com/Dreven95/LibraWeb

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "не получается сохранить"?  Возникает какая-то ошибка?  Не приходят данные в метод сервиса `save`?

Comment: @NowhereMan , возникает ошибка, сейчас прикреплю текст ошибки к вопросу

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120), особенно такие нечитабельные

Comment: @NowhereMan, вы попросили ошибку - я прикрепил. Что-то касаемо моего вопроса можете ответить?